Icon not found for Sveltekit 2.5, unplugin-icons 0.18.5
I am trying to get unplugin-icons working for in sveltekit 2.5 project.
package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^5.0.13",
    "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^2.2.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^3.0.1",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.5.7",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/eslint": "8.56.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.37.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.2.3",
    "sass": "^1.75.0",
    "svelte": "^4.2.15",
    "svelte-check": "^3.6.9",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "unplugin-icons": "^0.18.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vitest": "^1.5.0"
},

vite.config.ts
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite';

export default defineConfig({   
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        Icons({ compiler: 'svelte' })
    ],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: '@use "$lib/themes/common/variables.scss" as *;'
            }
        }
    },
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});

svelte.config.js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        })
    }
};

export default config;

src/app.d.ts
import 'unplugin-icons/types/svelte';

// See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#app
// for information about these interfaces
declare global {
    namespace App {
        // interface Error {}
        // interface Locals {}
        // interface PageData {}
        // interface PageState {}
        // interface Platform {}
    }
}

export {};

@types/declarations.d.ds
declare module 'virtual:icons/*';

+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import MdiAlarmOff from 'virtual:icons/mdi/alarm-off';
    import BiPencilSquare from 'virtual:icons/bi/pencil-square';
    import BiTrash from 'virtual:icons/bi/trash3';
</script>

<h1>Test</h1>
<BiPencilSquare />
<MdiAlarmOff />
<BiTrash />

I'm getting this error in browser for all of the icons
Icon `bi/trash3` not found

This is in the console


What if you leave declare module 'virtual:icons/*'; and import with import BiTrash from '~icons/bi/trash3';? And it looks like the icon packages are not installed? Like @iconify-json/mdi
